# No Next and Previous button while importing project in Intellij after intellij Idea 2019.2 update

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using **Intellij Idea Community edition**. It has been updated recently and the current version of **Intellij Idea is 2019.2 community edition**. I did not see any Next and Previous button in the dialog boxes while importing any maven or gradle project. Find the screen shorts.

[image]

[image]

As you can see there are no buttons in the bottom of the dialog boxes. I want to know whether it is the default behavior in the new edition of Intellij Idea or is there any problem with my installation.

Comment: This is the symptom of corrupted installation. Reinstalling and clearing the [config folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) should fix that. 
Meanwhile, can you show if there are custom [registry values](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-docker-registry.html)?

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov, Did you try extract the zip file ideaIC-2019.2.2.win.zip and did you try to import any project ? Is it working for you ? For me it is not working after making a new setup also in Windows 10.

Comment: Having the same issue with version of 2019.2.3

Comment: Seems it's a regression bug. According the [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135179) it's fixed (again) but hasn't released yet

Comment: Having the same issue here 2019.2.4 version... someone was able to fix it now?

Comment: Having the same problem with 2019.3 version (Build #IU-193.5233.102, built on November 27, 2019)

Comment: Yes @Alexander, I have also seen the same problem.

Comment: I have macOS 10.14.5 (18F132)

Comment: I have the same with: IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2 and macOS 10.15.2. Any news?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the following link, it was a regression bug.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-222331

Now it has been fixed. I am using Intellij Idea Ultimate **Version 2019.3.2**. Find below the attached screen shot below. I have redacted the licensed portion with black color. I hope that this bug may not be there in Community edition.

[image]